# Graphic Points are not working outside of viewDidLoad

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, graph

I've created a Graphic Class to show for user a graphic points choose accordingly with user information.

If I use the graphicView object and add points at viewDidLoad, the graphic is presented correctly, if not there, the graphic presents no data.

See below the code for the Graphics and the code when I am requesting to mark the points.

```
class GraphView: UIView {

private struct Constants {
    static let cornerRadiusSize = CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0)
    static let margin: CGFloat = 40.0
    static let topBorder: CGFloat = 30
    static let bottomBorder: CGFloat = 40
    static let colorAlpha: CGFloat = 0.3
    static let circleDiameter: CGFloat = 5.0
}

//1 - the properties for the gradient
var startColor: UIColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 14, green: 40, blue: 80)
var endColor: UIColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 14, green: 40, blue: 80)

//Weekly sample data
var graphPoints: [Int] = [0]

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let width = rect.width
    let height = rect.height

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                            byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners,
                            cornerRadii: Constants.cornerRadiusSize)
    path.addClip()

    //2 - get the current context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]

    //3 - set up the color space
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    //4 - set up the color stops
    let colorLocations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

    //5 - create the gradient
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace,
                              colors: colors as CFArray,
                              locations: colorLocations)!

    //6 - draw the gradient
    var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height)
    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient,
                               start: startPoint,
                               end: endPoint,
                               options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    //calculate the x point
    let margin = Constants.margin
    let columnXPoint = { (column:Int) -> CGFloat in
        //Calculate gap between points
        let spacer = (width - margin * 2 - 4) / CGFloat((self.graphPoints.count - 1))
        var x: CGFloat = CGFloat(column) * spacer
        x += margin + 2
        return x
    }

    // calculate the y point
    let topBorder: CGFloat = Constants.topBorder
    let bottomBorder: CGFloat = Constants.bottomBorder
    let graphHeight = height - topBorder - bottomBorder
    let maxValue = graphPoints.max()!
    let columnYPoint = { (graphPoint:Int) -> CGFloat in
        var y:CGFloat = CGFloat(graphPoint) / CGFloat(maxValue) * graphHeight
        y = graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
        return y
    }

    // draw the line graph
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    UIColor.white.setStroke()

    //set up the points line
    let graphPath = UIBezierPath()
    //go to start of line
    graphPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(0), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[0])))

    //add points for each item in the graphPoints array
    //at the correct (x, y) for the point
    for i in 1..<graphPoints.count {
        let nextPoint = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
        graphPath.addLine(to: nextPoint)
    }

    //Create the clipping path for the graph gradient

    //1 - save the state of the context (commented out for now)
    context.saveGState()

    //2 - make a copy of the path
    let clippingPath = graphPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath

    //3 - add lines to the copied path to complete the clip area
    clippingPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: columnXPoint(graphPoints.count - 1), y:height))
    clippingPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(0), y:height))
    clippingPath.close()

    //4 - add the clipping path to the context
    clippingPath.addClip()

    let highestYPoint = columnYPoint(maxValue)
    startPoint = CGPoint(x:margin, y: highestYPoint)
    endPoint = CGPoint(x:margin, y:self.bounds.height)

    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    context.restoreGState()

    //draw the line on top of the clipped gradient
    graphPath.lineWidth = 3.0
    graphPath.stroke()

    //Draw the circles on top of graph stroke
    for i in 0..<graphPoints.count {
        var point = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
        point.x -= Constants.circleDiameter / 2
        point.y -= Constants.circleDiameter / 2

        let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: Constants.circleDiameter, height: Constants.circleDiameter)))
        circle.fill()
    }

    //Draw horizontal graph lines on the top of everything
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()

    //top line
    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x:margin, y: topBorder))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - margin, y:topBorder))

    //center line
    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x:margin, y: graphHeight/2 + topBorder))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:width - margin, y:graphHeight/2 + topBorder))

    //bottom line
    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x:margin, y:height - bottomBorder))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:width - margin, y:height - bottomBorder))
    let color = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: Constants.colorAlpha)
    color.setStroke()

    linePath.lineWidth = 1.0
    linePath.stroke()
   }

}
```

I am trying to mark the points accordingly with the user input - see below:

```
func budgetAvailableCalculationFunction() {

let bankValue = (userSalary as NSString).integerValue
let bankPorcentage: Int = 100

let expenses = (userExpenses as NSString).integerValue

    let calculation1: Int = expenses * bankPorcentage
    let calculation2: Int = calculation1 / bankValue

    let cashPorcentageAvailable = calculation2

    let value: [Int] = [expenses]

    self.setupGraphy(points: value)

    progressView.progress = 0.0
    progress.completedUnitCount = Int64(cashPorcentageAvailable)
    progressView.setProgress(Float(self.progress.fractionCompleted), animated: true)
    progressView.progressTintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 239, green: 75, blue: 92)
    progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 239, green: 75, blue: 92)
    progressView.trackTintColor = .white
    progressView.clipsToBounds = false
    progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    porcentageLabelForMonth.text = "\(Int(self.progress.fractionCompleted * 100)) %"

}
```

The setupGraphy is just a function that returns an array of indexes that the user adds it.

Please note that using the same function at the viewDidLoad works:

*self.setupGraphy(points: [100, 400, 200, 250])*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Os4K.png)

Anyone?

Code for viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 245, green: 246, blue: 250)

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(LastTransactionsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "LastTransactionsCell")
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear

    let now = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy - LLLL"
    let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
    currentMonthLabel.text = nameOfMonth

    setupUIXViews()

    fetchUserInfo()
    //static data for now
    *self.setupGraphy(points: [100, 400, 200, 250])*

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2){
        self.budgetAvailableCalculationFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to see how you are calling it in viewDidLoad in the way that it works.  Mostly likely you are not making a call to update the view after the user input. Because if the code you have provided is working then it's most likely how you are calling it.

Comment: self.setupGraphy(points: [100, 400, 200, 250]) - this at viewDidLoad

Comment: So in `budgetAvailableCalculationFunction` you have verified that `let value: [Int] = [expenses]` is producing values?

Comment: Yes, also I add manually static data (and don't use DB data yet),  as above, it doesn't work outside of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Still think we are missing a piece of the puzzle. Show you code for full `viewDidload`.

Comment: Added the code above

Comment: How is `self.setupGraphy` defined?  Also starting to suspect that `setupUIXViews()` has something to do with the problem.

Comment: I'll keep trying here, still doesn't work... but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to fix (seems like a temporary fix) is by creating a new Int variable at the top of the project and passing the fetch data from the DB to these variables. That way I can use them at viewDidLoad instead of inside the fetch function.